# How can I sort alphabetically and numerically in bash?

Tags: bash

Right now I have a file as follows:

```
hostname=myhost1
id[12]=id12
id[3]=id3
id[2]=id2
id[7]=id7
alpha=a
```

Using sort in bash, how can I order my file as follows:

```
alpha=a
hostname=myhost1
id[2]=id2
id[3]=id3
id[7]=id7
id[12]=id12
```

I'm almost there... I get `id[12]=id12` before all of the other id's.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
sort -t '[' -nk2 file
alpha=a
hostname=myhost1
id[2]=id2
id[3]=id3
id[7]=id7
id[12]=id12
```

`-t` will set field separator as `[` and `-nk2` will sort the input numerically by field 2 wherever `[` is found.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way that I can give the first column priority though?  I need to be able to sort alphabetically first and then sort numerically if a `[` is found.

Comment: Yes you can do `sort -t '[' -k1 -nk2 file`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue with the following sort command:

```
sort -t '[' -k 1,1 -k 2,2n filename
```

Comment: Please do not post this as answer as this is pretty much what I had in my answer. You can edit your question if you want OR leave comments anywhere.